# How to support multiple api level in android development?

Tags: android, api

If you want to support multiple API levels and provide newer features with your app is running on a higher level API and reduce the features when your app is running on lower level API's what is a common design pattern that is used to solve this with Mono for Android?

Example would being wanting your application to not only Run on 2.3.x, 3.x, 4.0.x, 4.1.x but also take full advantage of the full API available on the device we are installed on. I know we can obviously use reflection to do this, but we really don't want to use that, and are looking for a cleaner design that would be easier to maintain and support.

** Updated:
For example, i want to use (Theme) 'Holo Light with Dark Action Bar' in my application, and I want to run in android 2.2.

Can android 2.2 support this?

Comment: android provide support libraries for the features which is introduces in newer API, those support libraries contains backward compatibility. Most of the new features(most which are useful) are ported back to lower api levels the same way. I don't think there is a feature you need in your app which is not ported back,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its simple. You can add the check of api version and perform your functionality accordingly. like :

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
     // only for gingerbread and newer versions
}else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
     // only for gingerbread and newer versions
}else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
     // only for ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH and newer versions
}else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
     // only for JELLY_BEAN and newer versions
}
```

if you want to support some higher api functionality to lower api then in that case you can use support library.